# Some computations of general unitary groups $GU(r,s)$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

This post can be regarded a start to understand this [MO Post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442686/).

Consider the following real Lie group
$$
\mathrm{GU}(r,s) := \{ g \in \mathrm{GL}_{r+s}(\mathbb{C}): {}^{t}\overline{g} I_{r,s} g = \lambda(g) I_{r,s}, \text{ for some } \lambda(g) \in \mathbb{R}^{\times} \},
$$
where $I_{r,s} = \mathrm{diag}(I_r, -I_s)$, $r \geq s \geq 0$.

**Question 1**: How to compute its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gu}(r,s)$? Moreover, what is the adjoint action $\mathrm{Ad}: \mathrm{GU}(r,s) \rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{gu}(r,s))$?

> I have searched in Math.SE and Mathoverflow, and it seems that no post has even touched this. I have read the proof of determining the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{u}(n)$ of the definite unitary group $U(n)$ without similitude. But I am still puzzled on how to compute $\mathfrak{gu}(r,s)$, as there are two generalizations: from the $(n,0)$-case to $(r,s)$-case, and carrying a (possibly nontrivial) similitude $\lambda: \mathrm{GU}(r,s) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\times}$. For the adjoint action, it seems that it is the usual matrix conjugation action as in linear groups. Yet the extra similitude factor makes me uncertain.

---

**My motivation** is considering the Shimura variety of $\mathrm{GU}(r,s)$:

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an imaginary quadratic extension, $r \geq s \geq 0$ and $n=r+s$. Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional $E$-vector space. Upon fixing a basis, it is equipped with an Hermitian pairing
$$
H: V \times V \rightarrow E, \quad (u,v) \mapsto u^{\ast} I_{r,s} v,
$$
where $u^{\ast} = {}^{t}\overline{u}$ and $I_{r,s} = \mathrm{diag}(I_r, -I_s)$. Then we define the **general unitary group** over $\mathbb{Q}$ as
$$
GU(r,s)(R) := \{g \in \mathrm{GL}_{E \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} R}(V \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} R) : H(gu,gv) = \lambda(g) H(u,v), \exists \lambda(g) \in R^{\times}, \forall u,v \in V \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} R  \},
$$
for any $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra $R$. Then its group of real points is the real Lie group at the beginning. I want to verify the axiom **(SV1)** of the "Shimura datum" $(\mathrm{GU}(r,s), X)$, so I hope to know the Lie algebra.

Here $X$ is the $GU(r,s)(\mathbb{R})$-conjugacy class of the Hodge structure
$$
h_0: \mathbb{S} \rightarrow \mathrm{GU}(r,s)_{\mathbb{R}}, \quad z \mapsto \mathrm{diag}(z I_p, \overline{z} I_q).
$$

**Question 2**: What does $X$ and its connected component $X^{+}$ look like? Moreover, I have heard someone said that the "$p=q$" case and the $p \neq q$ case is "totally different". But I have no feeling on this. Could someone elaborate on this?

> In Lan Kai-wen's [great note](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Ekwlan/articles/intro-sh-ex.pdf), he computed the $X = \mathcal{H}_{r,s}$ explicitly for the group $U(r,s)$, and only claimed that with the similitude, the $X$ should be $\mathcal{H}_{r,s}^{\pm}$. But I cannot see how the mysterious similitude factor $\lambda$ is involved in the computation. It looks like the shift from $\mathrm{GL}_2^{+}$ to $\mathrm{GL}_2$, but I cannot make it precise.

**Question 3**: Regarding the $G:=\mathrm{GU}(r,s)$ as an algebraic group over $\mathbb{R}$, what is its adjoint part $G^{\mathrm{ad}}$?

> So I may be able to check **(SV2)**.

Thank you all for answering and commenting (on either of the subquestions)! As this example of Shimura variety is frequently used, I tend to believe that these computations have been accomplished and written somewhere yet I cannot found. So any references are also welcome!

Comment: Is $\lambda$ a Lie group homomorphism?

Comment: @Chris Thank you for attention! In the definition, we do not *require* that $\lambda$ is a Lie group homomorphism. It just says that in this general unitary group, elements that "preserves the inner product *up to scalar*" are allowed as well. The scalar is denoted by $\lambda(g)$ since this scalar depends on $g$.

Comment: From the definition, I think one may be able to show that $\lambda$ is a group homomorphism (multiplicatively). Yet I am not sure whether it is smooth (i.e. a *Lie* group homomorphism) or not.

Comment: @Chris And I am considering of regarding the usual unitary group $U(r,s)$ as the "kernel" of $\lambda$. Then in some sence, we can have an extension of Lie algebra as $$0 \rightarrow \mathfrak{u}(r,s) \rightarrow \mathfrak{gu}(r,s) \rightarrow \mathrm{Lie}(\mathbb{R}^\times) \rightarrow 0.$$ But just as you pointed out, I cannot make it precise since I am not certain on what structures $\lambda$ may preserve, and whether it is enough or not to induce an extension of Lie algebraic....

Comment: @Chris (Sorry the “Lie algebraic” above should be “*Lie algebras*”.) And moreover, even if I can get such an extension of Lie algebras, the short exact sequence in the previous comment may not split, so it is still so vague to me what the Lie algebra of $GU(r,s)$ looks like. Sorry for posting such long comments. Thank you so much for your attention and help! :).

Comment: What’s the map taking $GU$ to $\mathbb{R}^\times$?

Comment: @Chris The silimitude factor $\lambda$.